# На Android всплывает footer и aside страницы (html/css). Флекс не кроссбраузерный?

Tags: android, css, адаптивная-верстка

Обнаружила такую проблему на своем сайте. Именно во встроенном браузере на Android. В Опере, Макстоне и Dolphin Browser, Next Browser тоже, как оказалось. На других ОС (и в браузерах FireFox, Google Chrome и Puffin для Android) всё в порядке.

Тут мне подсказали, что во флекс может быть проблема. Может, префиксы нужны какие-то? Где их берут?

Всплывает только в портретной ориентации (`max-width`?), в ландшафтной - всё на своем месте.

А может, это не в `footer` и `aside` проблема? На android, похоже, блок `article` вообще пустой и минимальной высоты. Отображается под хэдером как узкая полоска. А должен бы содержать весь тот текст, который "уполз" под футер.

Я новичок в css, первый мой сайт с его использованием. Помогите решить, будьте добры. Стили такие:

```
   @charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */



* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}  

/* Сброс стилей */



/* Конец сброса стилей*/


    html { 

    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%; } /* Браузерное умолчание, т.е. 16px  */     
h1 { 
font-size: 5vmin; 
font-size: 1.5rem; 
}   
h2 { 
font-size: 3.5vmin; 
font-size: 1.2rem; 
text-align: center;
line-height: 1;
}   

h4 { 
font-size: 3vmin; 
font-size: 1rem; 
font-weight: normal;
text-align: center;
display:inline;}  

h5 { 
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.5;
}     


h6 { 
text-align: center;
line-height: 1.5;
}     

p { 
font-size: 3vmin; 
font-size: 0.9rem; 
}

.accordion h3 {
font-size: 2.2vmin;
font-size: 0.7rem;
display: block; 
}   

.title_block {
    line-height: 1.7; /* 34px */}

#map {display:block}        







    body {
         font-size: 100%;
    line-height: 1.6875;
    font-family: Georgia;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    }

    #main {

        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row;
    }

    #main > article {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
        border: 1px solid #87a7b1;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: #F7F7F7;
        flex: 3 1 60%;
        order: 2;
        text-align:justify;
    }


    #main > aside {
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 7px;
        border: 1px solid #8888bb;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: #eceeec;
        flex: 1 6 20%;
        order: 3;
        border: 1px solid #9cb6be;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        padding-bottom: 35px;
    }

    header {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 100px;
        border: 1px solid #9cb6be;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: #e4ebed;
    }

    footer  {
        position: relative;
        display: block;
        margin: 4px;
        padding: 5px;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 85px;
        border: 1px solid #9cb6be;
        border-radius: 7pt;
        background: #C9D1C7;    

    }


img {
    max-width: 100%;
}



a { color:#0043AF; } 



    /* Too narrow to support three columns */
    @media all and (max-width: 640px) {
        #main, #page {
            flex-direction: column;
        }

        #main > article, #main > nav, #main > aside {
        /* Return them to document order */
            order: 0;
        }

         #main > nav, #main > aside, header
         {
            min-height: 40px;
            max-height: 500px;
        }

        footer {min-height: 100px;}
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Заюзайте хром :)

Comment: В хроме на ноутбуке - все нормально. В том числе и в разных разрешениях (инструменты разработчика)  А на эмуляторе android*a нет у меня хрома.Хотя могу поставить. Утром отпишусь

Comment: Да Установила Google Chrome. В нем - все хорошо отображается.

Comment: Никто не юзает встроенный браузер :) Не помню с какого но на самых новых дефолтный браузер это и есть хром :) так что можете расслпбиться. А за эту проблему взяться когда надо будет поддерживать старых мобилы (никогда?)

Comment: Спасибо, конечно :) НО! В опере такая же проблема. Так что решить как-то нужно. А у меня есть пара знакомых, кто именно дефолтным браузером в андроид пользуются. Может, и больше, я просто никогда не интересовалась. Статистика говорит, что до 6% пользуют встроенный браузер. И Оперу 6% используют. Уже 12 получается. Надо решить проблему.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Нет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25337814/flexbox-isnt-working-in-android-web-browser-in-android-4-4-2)

Стандартный android браузер (и видимо остальные вышеперечисленные) не умеют нормально отображать `display: flex`. Он у вас тут:

```
#main {
    ...
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
}
```

В медиазапросах замените на `display: block`, там где по факту у вас все в столбик и он не нужен:

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
    #main, #page {
        display:block;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: ОГРОМНОЕ СПАСИБО!